# replace first occurence after a match on all lines for all matches using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to write a short script to change tex syntax into rst syntax because in some instances, it's easier to just write `$some math$` instead of `` :math:`some math` ``.

Now say I have a file that has multiple inline math occurences, e.g.

```
foo.rst:

Only $one$ inline math.
This $line$ has $some$ more $math$ then $the$ first one
```

So far, what I have working is the simple case where there is only one occurence (first line in example file), but `sed` seems to match the last `$` in the line, not the first after the first match. This is my result:

```
 $ sed -E 's/\$(.+)\$/:math:`\1`/g' foo.rst
Only :math:`one` inline math.
This :math:`line$ has $some$ more $math$ then $others`
```

How do I need to change my sed command to match all `$` pair-wise?

Comment: Use ``sed 's/\$\([^$]*\)\$/:math:`\1`/g' file > newfile``

Comment: Ah, that seems to do the trick. Didn't know the 'greedy' terminology, so duplicate indeed. Thanks for the extremely quick reply!

Comment: The point is to changed `.*` to a negated bracket expression `[^$]` that matches any char but `$`. It is working because the right-hand boundary is a single `$` char. If it is multicharacter, you would have to use Perl, or other work-arounds.